# React Native: Setting the width of a view equal to its height when using percentages

Tags: css, react-native

I have this stylesheet, and I'm trying to make the width of this equal to the height when I set height as a percentage. I the following with no success:

```
art: {
    height: "70%",
    width: styles.podcastArt.height,
    marginRight:10,
    marginTop:10,
    marginBottom:10,
},
```

Any ideas or direction would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

set `aspectRatio: 1`

```
art: {
    height: "70%",
    aspectRatio: 1,
    marginRight:10,
    marginTop:10,
    marginBottom:10,
},
```

Comment: react-native is awesome because of these little shortcuts :)

Comment: aspectRatio: 1 works only when we define width first eg. 
width: "70%",
aspectRatio: 1,